# jQuery: replace body text occurance with input value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, replace

I want to replace an occurrence of data between two specific characters in a textarea with the data of an input field by the click of a button. So far I have this:

```js
$("#apply_capping").click(function() {
    $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(?<=\*).*?(?=\))/g,$("#cap").val()));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popunder-capping" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="background-color:#fff;color:#000">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
    <label class="cappings">Hour(s):</label> <input type="number" min="1" max="168" class="select-selected" id="cap" name="cap" size="1" maxlength="3"> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    <button id="apply_capping" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Apply
    </button>
</div>

<div class="portlet-body">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <label style="width:100%;">
                <i class="fas fa-code fa-fw"></i> Source Code
            </label>
            <br/>
<textarea id="parammed_popunder" rows="3" width="200" class="form-control">
wait:(3600*24)           </textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On  my end it actually copies the value from the element with id cap and replaces it in the text area. The problem is that it can't be used twice unless page refreshed, and the value disappears from the input. How should I approach this?

Comment: The problem is that you are replacing the html so the dom elements that is bound to the click event does not exist after the click event.

Comment: Thanks! How to reference only textarea with id parammed_popunder in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

```
$("#apply_capping").click(function() {
    $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(?<=\*).*?(?=\))/g,$("#cap").val()));
    });
});
```

to:

```
$("#apply_capping").click(function() {
    $("body").find("textarea#parammed_popunder").val(function() {
        return $(this).val().replace(/(?<=\*).*?(?=\))/g,$("#cap").val());
    });
});
```

The problem is that your current code, changes the `html` on your site and by that the dom elements that are bound to the click event does not exist anymore.

```js
$("#apply_capping").click(function() {
    $("body").find("textarea#parammed_popunder").val(function() {
        return $(this).val().replace(/(?<=\*).*?(?=\))/g,$("#cap").val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popunder-capping" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="background-color:#fff;color:#000">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
    <label class="cappings">Hour(s):</label> <input type="number" min="1" max="168" class="select-selected" id="cap" name="cap" size="1" maxlength="3"> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    <button id="apply_capping" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Apply
    </button>
</div>

<div class="portlet-body">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <label style="width:100%;">
                <i class="fas fa-code fa-fw"></i> Source Code
            </label>
            <br/>
<textarea id="parammed_popunder" rows="3" width="200" class="form-control">
wait:(3600*24)           </textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much! Looks like you answered faster than I could accept an answer. Have to wait 6 more min.

Comment: No problem @lion Happy to help, if this solved your problem please consider marking it as solved, so other users know that it solved your problem